# Why can't I update my J2ME RecordStore?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, rms

I basically want my Midlet the ability to edit records.

I have this code

the information is added as follows

```
 protected void searchForNameToEdit()
 {
          Editrecord.deleteAll();

    try
    {

        rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("Detail", true);
        RecordEnumeration re = rs.enumerateRecords(new NameMatcher(EditSearch.getString()), null, false);
        while (re.hasNextElement())
        {
            byte [] recordBuffer = re.nextRecord();
            String record = new String(recordBuffer);


            int endOfName = record.indexOf(";");
            int endOfDesc = record.indexOf(";" , endOfName + 1);
            int endOfTown = record.indexOf(";", endOfDesc + 1);
            int endOfPlace = record.indexOf(";", endOfTown + 1);
            int endOfSDay = record.indexOf("/", endOfPlace +1);
            int endOfSMonth = record.indexOf("/",endOfSDay + 1);
            int endOfSYear = record.indexOf(";", endOfSMonth + 1);
            int endOfEDay = record.indexOf("/", endOfSYear + 1);
            int endOfEMonth = record.indexOf("/", endOfEDay + 1);
            int endOfEYear = record.indexOf(";", endOfEMonth + 1);
            int endOfComment = record.indexOf(";", endOfEYear + 1);
            int endOfRating = record.indexOf (";", endOfComment + 1);
            int endOfReview = record.indexOf (";", endOfRating + 1);


            String Name = record.substring(0, endOfName);
            String Desc = record.substring(endOfName + 1, endOfDesc);
            String Town = record.substring(endOfDesc + 1, endOfTown);
            String Place= record.substring(endOfTown + 1, endOfPlace);
            String SDay = record.substring(endOfPlace +1, endOfSDay);
            String SMonth = record.substring(endOfSDay + 1, endOfSMonth);
            String SYear = record.substring(endOfSMonth + 1, endOfSYear);
            String EDay = record.substring(endOfSYear + 1, endOfEDay);
            String EMonth = record.substring(endOfEDay + 1, endOfEMonth);
            String EYear = record.substring(endOfEMonth + 1, endOfEYear);
            String Comment = record.substring(endOfEYear + 1, endOfComment);
            String Rating = record.substring(endOfComment + 1, endOfRating);
            String Review = record.substring(endOfRating + 1, endOfReview);


            EtxtName = new TextField("Name of Event: ", Name, 15, TextField.ANY);
            EdescEvent = new TextField("Describe the Event : ", Desc, 250, TextField.ANY);
            EtownEvent = new TextField("Name of Town : ", Town, 50, TextField.ANY);
            EplaceEvent = new TextField("Name of Place : ", Place, 25, TextField.ANY);
            EcommentEvent = new TextField("Any comments : ", Comment, 300, TextField.ANY);
            EStartDate = new TextField("Start Date : ", SDay + "/" + SMonth + "/" + SYear +";", 300, TextField.ANY);
            EEndDate =new TextField("End Date : ", EDay + "/" + EMonth + "/" + EYear +";", 300, TextField.ANY);
            EEventRating = new TextField("Event Rating : ", Rating, 10, TextField.ANY);
            EOverallReview = new TextField("Overall Review : ", Review, 300, TextField.ANY);


            Editrecord.append(EtxtName);
            Editrecord.append(EdescEvent);
            Editrecord.append(EtownEvent);
            Editrecord.append(EplaceEvent);
            Editrecord.append(EStartDate);
           // Editrecord.append("Start Date; " + SDay + "/" + SMonth + "/" + SYear);
            //Editrecord.append("End Date; " + EDay + "/" + EMonth + "/" + EYear);
            Editrecord.append(EEndDate);
            Editrecord.append(EcommentEvent);
            Editrecord.append(EEventRating);
            Editrecord.append(EOverallReview);




    }
        rs.closeRecordStore();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        mAlertConfirmDetailsSaved.setString("Couldn't read details");
        System.err.println("Error accessing database");
    }

    Display.setCurrent(Editrecord);

}
```

and this is the method to perform the update

```
protected void PerformUpdate()
{
    int id;

    strEName = EtxtName.getString();
    strEDescEvent = EdescEvent.getString();
    strETown = EtownEvent.getString();
    strEPlace = EplaceEvent.getString();

    strStartDate = EStartDate.getString();

    strEndDate = EEndDate.getString();

    strECommentE = EcommentEvent.getString();
    strERating = EEventRating.getString();
    strEReview = EOverallReview.getString();


        String detailsToUpdate = strEName + ";" +"\n"+
                                 strEDescEvent + ";" + "\n"+
                                 strETown + ";" + "\n" +
                                 strEPlace + ";"+ "\n" +
                                 strEStartDate + ";" + "\n" +
                                 strEEndDate + ";" + "\n" +
                                 strECommentE + ";"+ "\n" +
                                 strERating + ";"+ "\n" +
                                 strEReview + ";";

    if (listOfIDs != null)
    {

        try {
            //RecordStore
                    rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("Detail", true);
            for (Enumeration e = listOfIDs.elements() ; e.hasMoreElements() ;)
            {
                id  = ((Integer)e.nextElement()).intValue();
                byte [] detailsBuffer = detailsToUpdate.getBytes();
             rs.setRecord(id,detailsBuffer, 0, detailsBuffer.length);

            }

            rs.closeRecordStore();

            mAlertDeleteDone.setString("  Selected record updated");

            }
        catch(Exception e)
            {
            mAlertDeleteDone.setString("Couldn't update record");
            System.err.println("Error accessing database");
            }

    } 
    else
    {
        mAlertDeleteDone.setString("No records to update");
    }

    Display.setCurrent(mAlertDeleteDone, mOpeningForm);
}
```

All I keep getting is the else outcome of No records to update and I have no reason why?

Please help or send me a helpful tutorial  thanks

Comment: You get that else clause if listOFIds is null, but you've not given us the code that sets that. So, it's presumably null and your recordstore code isn't getting called at all?

Comment: Yeah, I'd vote it up to as there is just no other reference to listOFIds in the code provided.

Comment: even after your edit, you're still not telling us how listOfIds is set. So we can't help you.